# nodejs callback exec result

Tags: node.js, callback, exec, ping

I am new to node and having some headaches with async callback.

i am writing a script to ping a list of servers, and wish to return an array for their status ('OK' if all hosts are 'pingable')

```
hostaddr = [ '10.102.14.20', '10.102.14.21', '10.102.14.22' ];
pingstat = testping(hostaddr, function(err, callback) {
    console.log(callback);
});


const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var testping = function(hostaddr,callback) {    
    var pingstat = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < hostaddr.length; i++) {
        const child = exec('ping -c 1 ' + hostaddr[i],
            (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                if (error !== null) {
                    console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
                } else {
                    pingstat.push("OK");
                    callback(pingstat);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

i wish the testping function will return pingstat ['OK,'OK','OK'] if ping success for all the hosts, but my code doesn't work, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var testping = function(hostaddr,callback) {    
    var pingstat = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < hostaddr.length; i++) {
        const child = exec('ping -c 1 ' + hostaddr[i],
            (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
                console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
                if (error !== null) {
                    console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
                    pingstat.push("ERROR");
                } else {
                    pingstat.push("OK");
                }

                if (pingstat.length == hostaddr.length) {
                    callback (pingstat);
                }   
            });
    }
}

var hostaddr = [ '10.102.14.20', '10.102.14.21', '10.102.14.22' ];
var pingResults = null;
var hostaddr = [ '192.168.2.54' ,'192.168.2.541'];
testping(hostaddr, function(results) {
    console.log("Ping results: " + results);
    // Save results.
    pingResults = results;
});

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/pingResults',  function(req, res, next) {
    res.status(200);
        res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.end(JSON.stringify({pingResults: pingResults}));    
});
app.get('/pingresultslive',  function(req, res, next) {
    testping(hostaddr, function(results) {
        console.log("Ping results: " + results);
        res.status(200);
        res.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
        res.end(JSON.stringify({pingResults: pingResults}));
    });
});
var httpPort = 8081;
console.log('Listening on port: ' + httpPort); 

app.listen(httpPort);
```

You can also include more error information in the result array by appending error details to the "ERROR" string.

So, you can now save the results and query with curl:
    curl http://localhost:8081/pingresults
Or you can do it live
    curl http://localhost:8081/pingresultslive

Comment: i actually want to print pingstat to my html, can you give me more hint on how to store pingstat as an array so i can print it later with res.end(pingstat), instead of logging to console.

Comment: I've updated the answer now to include the res.end part!

Comment: i can log the right 'Ping results: OK,OK,OK', however, html only receive null. Dont know why the result isnt pass to HTML correctly

Comment: How are you updating your HTML, are you calling the node.js webservice or are you doing it on the clientside, e.g. embedded JavaScript in the page?

Comment: logging the correct result to console, but get and empty json{
"pingResults": null
}

Comment: actually its a form for user to input the ip addresses, press submit will return the ping result

Comment: Ok, cool, so you need to update the HTML DOM in the callback method itself.  e.g testping(hostaddr, function(results) {
    console.log("Ping results: " + results);
    // Save results.
    pingResults = results;
});

Comment: Something like: document.write(result)!